# How to resolve third-party XML schema collisions?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I'm working with a set of schema descriptor files written by a third party.  I need to generate JAXB stubs for them.  Each XSD defines a different message type, along with a number of supporting simple and complex types.  Many of the types are common to each XSD, but rather than factor them out into a separate XSD, the authors chose to define them in each namespace.  This creates a grundle of namespace collisions when I try to compile the XSD's using xjc into a single package.  I'm forced to separate them into unique packages.  The problem is that this makes them non-interchangeable, when they should be.  I have to do a lot of extra conversion to use data from one message type in a different message type.

My question: is there some way (binding customization?) I can instruct xjc to use one java class for each shared type, rather than unique classes spread across different packages?

Here's a simplified example.  I've got two XSD's, one for an insert message and another for a response message.  The response is meant to reference an insert message.

```
<!-- insert.xsd -->
<xs:schema
    xmlns="msg.insert"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="msg.insert">

    <xs:element name="Message" type="Message" />

    <xs:complexType name="Message">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element 
              maxOccurs="1" 
              minOccurs="1" 
              name="MessageId" 
              type="Identifier" />

            <xs:element 
              maxOccurs="1" 
              minOccurs="1" 
              name="SequenceId" 
              type="Identifier" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Identifier">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element 
              maxOccurs="1" 
              minOccurs="1" 
              name="ID" 
              type="xs:string" />

            <xs:element 
              maxOccurs="1" 
              minOccurs="1" 
              name="Created" 
              type="xs:dateTime" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Here's the second XSD...

```
<!-- response.xsd -->
<xs:schema
    xmlns="msg.response"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="msg.response">

    <xs:element name="Message" type="Message" />

    <xs:complexType name="Message">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element 
              maxOccurs="1" 
              minOccurs="1" 
              name="MessageId" 
              type="Identifier" />

            <xs:element 
              maxOccurs="1" 
              minOccurs="1" 
              name="SequenceId" 
              type="Identifier" />

            <xs:element 
              maxOccurs="1" 
              minOccurs="1" 
              name="ReferenceId" 
              type="Identifier" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Identifier">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element 
              maxOccurs="1" 
              minOccurs="1" 
              name="ID" 
              type="xs:string" />

            <xs:element 
              maxOccurs="1" 
              minOccurs="1" 
              name="Created" 
              type="xs:dateTime" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Note the `Identifier` complex type is identical in both schemas.  It can and *should* be interchangeable between message types.  But when I run xjc thus...

`xjc -d java -p example.msg insert.xsd response.xsd`

...I get collisions on the Message, Identifier, and ObjectFactory classes as follows.

```
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "example.msg.Message" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 8 of insert.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "Message" is generated from here.
  line 8 of response.xsd

[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "example.msg.Identifier" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 15 of insert.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "Identifier" is generated from here.
  line 16 of response.xsd

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 8 of insert.xsd

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 8 of response.xsd
```

I completely understand why xjc is complaining, I'm trying to find a way to coax xjc into using a common class for the Identifier type, as well as resolve the collisions in the ObjectFactory class.  One solution would be to factor the common types out into a separate namespace and reference them from each message type's XSD, but as mentioned these are all written by a third party and I don't have the ability to change them.

For now I'm compiling each XSD into a separate java package.  This works but is very, very cumbersome.

The error output suggests there's a way to do this with a binding customization, but so far I haven't figured out how to make that work.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know a lot about JAXB, but my guess is that you will have a fundamental problem with trying to get what you want.  You have two different "Identifier" types, as they are in two different namespaces, which means they must necessarily be encoded differently.  I would be surprised if JAXB was designed to support producing different encodings from the same class.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right, but the error output says a class customization can resolve the issue.  I'm still trying to figure that out.

Comment: I give up.  I see how to change the generated class' name, but I don't see how to change the package.  There's an implClass attribute on the <jxb:class> element, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can solve this problem just by adding the following custom arg in the *wsimport* command:

```
-B-XautoNameResolution (without spaces)
```

This way, any name conflict will be automatically removed when parsing the xml.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with a similar issue to compile a huge library of XSD ( >1.8K XSD files) with a large rate of duplicated types between the XSDs.

The only feasible solution I've found was to generate an intermediate model with default packages per namespace, and process that afterward with Java codemodel moving all type classes into a single package, collapsing the duplicated classes.

Finally, I had to hack the marshaling to avoid namespace aware in the collapsed classes.

It seems like a crazy solution but worked just fine.

BTW -XautoNameResolution is just a way to automatically rename the duplicated type classes, but it does not solve the duplication issue.